# Does Microsoft make available the .obj files for its CRT versions to enable whole program optimization on CRT codepaths?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Given the potential performance improvements from LTCG (link time code generation, or whole program optimization), which requires the availability of .obj files, does Microsoft make available the .obj files for the various flavors of its MSVCRT releases? One would think this would be a good place for some potential gain. Not sure what they have to lose since the IL that is generated in the .obj files is not documented and processor specific.

Comment: Just run nmake.exe on the makefile provided in the vc\crt\src subdirectory.  Not all source code is available, but the missing parts are shipped with .obj and .lib files.

Comment: Actually, LTCG requires the availability of .obj files _built with /LTCG_. "Ordinary" .obj files are not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static library is basically just a collection of .obj files mushed (that's a technical term) together into a single file, with a directory added so the linker can find each on easily. If you use the static library, it should be able to include them in the global optimization phase.

Comment: Nope - the .obj's inside aren't built with /LTCG so they can't participate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but considering they provide full source code to the CRT there's no reason you can't make your own.